# Generating multiple Gradle Tar tasks depending on previous task's output

Tags: gradle

I have a feeling the answer to this is "it's impossible" but I figured I would ask anyway.

Let's say I have a task that generates an arbitrary number of directories (ie, I won't know at build time how many directories could have been generated):

```
task makeSampleFiles {
    doLast {
        mkdir 'build/a'
        mkdir 'build/b'
        ...
        file('build/a/a.out').text = 'a'
        file('build/b/b.out').text = 'b'
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to generate a `Tar` task for each of the directories found. For example:

```
fileTree("build/").visit {
    if (it.isDirectory()) {
        def variant = it.name
        def t = tasks.create(name: "generateTar${variant}", type: Tar) {
            from "./build/${variant}/"
            baseName = "dist-${variant}"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, it looks like I can only create those tasks at configuration time. At which point, `makeSampleFiles` hasn't run yet, so there are no files.

Is there any way to generate and run tasks during the Gradle execution phase? Or any other way to generate an arbitrary number of TARs during execution phase, similar to how you can have multiple `copy{}` specs in a `doLast`?

Comment: indeed it's not possible to create and add tasks during the *execution* phase. but do you really need to create these multiple Tar tasks ( do you need to invoke these tasks manually, or to see these tasks in the Project's tasks list)?  else you could create a single task , similar to your 'makeSampleFiles' , that would iterate other `build/` subfolder and create a *tar* archive for each. using **ant** `tar`for example.

Comment: I indeed do not really need to invoke them manually or see them in the task list (although I think I could do this with task rules), so that's not a requirement. A single task would work. I hadn't thought about ant.tar - I think that would indeed work. Let me try it.

Comment: Rules seems to fit the idea quite well here.

Comment: I think that with Task Rules, you will still have the same issue:  you will need to define rules at configuration phase level, while the list of directories won't be known until execution phase.

Comment: Rules do work here, however I still have the issue of how do I create a 'dependsOn' to the task names? I'll still need to define which tasks I need to dependOn at configuration time, for which I need the list of directories...

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Please go ahead and add an Answer to this question, your solution to use ant tar worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it's not possible to create and add tasks during the execution phase, but as discussed in comments above, if you don't really need to create several tasks (one per folder / archive to produce), then you could implement this with a single task that would iterate other the different directories, and create a tar archive for each.

Something like that will work:

```
// your initial task which creates the directories
task makeSampleFiles {
    doLast {
        mkdir 'build/pkg/a'
        mkdir 'build/pkg/b'
        // ....
        file('build/pkg/a/a.out').text = 'a'
        file('build/pkg/b/b.out').text = 'b'
    }
}

// the task responsible to create tar archives
task makeTarAchives {
    dependsOn makeSampleFiles
    doLast {
        fileTree("build/").visit {
            if (it.isDirectory()) {
                def variant = it.name
                ant.tar(destfile: "build/dist-${variant}.tar", basedir: "build/$variant")
            }
        }
    }
}
```